# Create table in SAS using DB2 timestamp

Tags: sql, sas, db2

We've recently gotten the accelerator (IDAA) working on our DB2, which I mainly access using SAS.

This requires us, due to network issues, to create tables first, before inserting rows.

My problem is creating a table with the correct timestamp format, I can create the table using a select statement, but this is very slow, but here I can see the format in SAS is DATETIME30.6

But if I try something like:

```
RSUBMIT prod_acc;
Proc delete data=user.table1; run; %PUT &sqlxrc &sqlxmsg; 
proc sql inobs=MAX stimer feedback noerrorstop;
 connect to db2(ssid=server);
 create table user.table1
(
            date datetime30.6
            ,reference char(16)
            ,transact char(20)
            ,alias char(60)
            ,amount decimal(15,2)
            ,currency char(3)
   );
%PUT &sqlxrc &sqlxmsg; 
quit;
run;
```

Which gives the following in the log

```
 (
15               date datetime30.6
                      -----------
                      1         22
                                200
WARNING 1-322: Assuming the symbol DATE was misspelled as datetime30.

ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a quoted string,
              an integer constant, ), ',', CHECK, DISTINCT, FORMAT, INFORMAT, LABEL, LEN,
              LENGTH, NOT, PRIMARY, REFERENCES, TRANSCODE, UNIQUE, ^, ~.

ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.
```

And if I look in DB2, the column has the type timestmp which SAS don't recognize as a type.

```
 (
31               date timestmp
                      --------
                      22
                      76
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: CHAR, CHARACTER, DATE, DEC,
              DECIMAL, DOUBLE, FLOAT, INT, INTEGER, NUM, NUMERIC, REAL, SMALLINT, VARCHAR.

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
```

Tried googling and found a lot of different versions of answers, but nothing I can see is relevant to this, the closest was something about manually creating the format, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `USER` the name of a libref that you have defined in SAS or the name of a database/schema in your remote DB2 database?  The syntax you have written is SAS code and so it is assuming USER is a libref.  If you want to push code into the remote database use the `execute` statement inside of PROC SQL.

Comment: User is my windows user, just a way not to give away information :D

Comment: Using your username as a libref is probably not going to work very well since it is likely to be longer than 8 characters.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably more natural in SAS to define a table's structure using a DATA step rather than PROC SQL.

```
data userdb.table1;
 stop;
 length date 8 reference $16 transact $20 alias $60 amount 8 currency $3 ;
 format date datetime30.6 amount 15.2 ;
run;
```

If your libref is pointing to a database then you should be able to use `DBTYPE=` dataset option to tell SAS what data types to use for your fields in the external database. At least it works for Teradata.  These dataset options should work inside PROC SQL also.

```
proc delete data=userdb.table1; run;
data userdb.table1
(dbtype=
 ( date='timestamp'
   reference='varchar(16)'
   transact='varchar(20)'
   alias='varchar(60)'
   amount='decimal(15,2)'
   currency='char(3)'
 )
);
 stop;
 length date 8 reference $16 transact $20 alias $60 amount 8 currency $3 ;
 format date datetime30.6 amount 15.2 ;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just:

```
 create table user.table1
 (
         "date" TIMESTAMP(6)
        ,reference char(16)
        ,transact char(20)
        ,alias char(60)
        ,amount decimal(15,2)
        ,currency char(3)
);
```

? Remember, in DB2, `date` is a reserved word, and then it's always safe to put that into double quotes. Alternatively, use a non-reserved word for the column name, like `dt` or so.

Comment: Good advice, but as the code is written in the question it's not using DB2 syntax but SAS syntax (where `"` does not have that meaning).

Comment: Date is not really called date, and yes it's a reserved word.

But no, I get the syntax error expecting one of the following types.....

Answer (score 0):

These two lines are incongruous:

```
connect to db2(ssid=server);
create table user.table1
```

The first creates a connection for a pass-through query, while the latter creates the table using the libname engine. In this case your first statement is irrelevant as it's not used; you should remove it (unless you use it later and just left it in by mistake in your example).

Since you used the libname syntax, you must follow `SAS` syntax rather than `DB2`.  There is no specification for `datetime` type in the create table statement, specifically under the [column-definition](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/69822/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0v236a0ti4nmen1mmw4gexjd0tg.htm) documentation page.  Instead you have this list to choose from:

> - CHARACTER | VARCHAR <(width)> indicates a character column with a column width of width. The default column width is eight characters.
> - INTEGER | SMALLINT indicates an integer column.
> - DECIMAL | NUMERIC | FLOAT <(width<, ndec>)> indicates a floating-point column with a column width of width and ndec decimal
>     places.
> - REAL | DOUBLE PRECISION indicates a floating-point column.
> - DATE indicates a date column.

The way I find best to specify datetime (meaning, most likely to work as you expect) is not to use `date` but `numeric`, and then use the `format` argument to define it as datetime.

```
proc sql;
  create table table1
    (       date num format=datetime30.6
            ,reference char(16)
            ,transact char(20)
            ,alias char(60)
            ,amount decimal(15,2)
            ,currency char(3)
   );
quit;
```

However, I would suggest your *best* choice is to use passthrough to create the table, so you can use `DB2` syntax - since you're creating a table there, not in SAS itself.